# I always thought that he was a great teacher

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

1. I'**ve always** thought that he **was** a great teacher.
2. I **always** thought that he **was** a great teacher.

If I've just changed my opinion about him being a great teacher, can I say that (2) and (3) mean the same thing?

If they're different, then in what situation one would use sentence (1)?

Comment: Sometimes they'll mean the same thing. But your second version is more likely if you're intending to continue by saying ***but** I no longer believe that*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, do you mean the speaker of (1) **still** believes he **is** a great teacher?

Comment: Normally, the implication of using Present Perfect is that the action so described *continues up until time of speaking*, yes. But that doesn't mean there's anything syntactically invalid about saying something *I've always assumed the earth was flat, but I now realise that was just dumb.* It's just that we're more *likely* to use Simple Past in such contexts. Well - we're more likely to use Simple Past *as a general principle*, so there usually has to be *some* reason for using Present Perfect instead. But perhaps it's just *that's what I thought **right up until a few minutes ago***.